# Swift Combine: Merge publishers of different types

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am trying to merge multiple publishers that are of different types.

I have publishers of type string and a publisher of type, however when I merge them using `MergeMany` or `CombineLatest` I get a type mismatch error.

Is there anyway to merge publishers of different types? See the code example below:

```swift
@Published var str1: String?
@Published var str2: String?
@Published var image: Image?
        
Publishers.MergeMany($str1, $str2, $image)
    .removeDuplicates()
    .sink { _ in
        //...
    }
    .store(in: &bag)
```

Comment: I think one important factor is what you're expecting to get inside the `sink` -- does the `_` imply that you don't actually need to get a parameter there and that you just care more about the fact that one of them has been updated?

Comment: Yes, all I care about is that one of them has changed. One thing I forgot to include in my code example is that I would like to remove any duplicates if possible, but isn't required if there's a another way to implement this.

Comment: There's something fishy there, why are you publishing an `Image`? That's a SwiftUI view, it's unlikely you'll get something useful out of that. Or were you trying to publish a `UIImage` instead?

Comment: Combine, Merge and Zip have counterparts that accept different types, have you tried `Merge3`?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you had no other `@Published` properties, the easiest thing to do would be to use `objectWillChange`:

```
self.objectWillChange
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .sink {
            print("objectWillChange...", self.str1, self.str2, self.image)
        }
        .store(in: &bag)
```

However, this *does not* give you the remove duplicates that you mentioned in the comments.

If you want, that, you can get a little more complicated with things:

```
Publishers.MergeMany(
            $str1.dropFirst().removeDuplicates().map({ _ in }).eraseToAnyPublisher(),
            $str2.dropFirst().removeDuplicates().map({ _ in }).eraseToAnyPublisher(),
            $image.dropFirst().removeDuplicates().map({ _ in }).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        )
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .sink {
            print("MergeMany...", self.str1, self.str2, self.image)
        }
        .store(in: &bag)
```

*(There may be a prettier way than my `map. { _ in }` to remove the return type)*

The above method seems to work effectively for removing the individual duplicate elements and only triggering the `sink` when one of them has changed.

Answer (score 3):

@jnpdx's answer gets the job done. I'm focusing on this question from OP:

> Is there anyway to merge publishers of different types?

It is important to realize the difference between Merge and CombineLatest operators since they are quite different, semantically.

Check out RxMarbles for [Merge](https://rxmarbles.com/#merge) and [CombineLatest](https://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest).
Merge requires the inner publishers to have the same `Output` and emits a single value whenever one emits.
CombineLatest publishes a tuple containing the latest values for each inner publisher.

I would write this like so:

```swift
@Published var str1: String?
@Published var str2: String?
@Published var image: Image?
    
func setUpBindings() {
    Publishers.CombineLatest3($str1, $str2, $image)
        .sink { _ in 
            //...
        }
        .store(in: &bag)
}
```

Since tuples can't conform to Equatable (yet), you can't leverage `removeDuplicates()` on the resulting publisher.

Like @jnpdx wrote, an approach could be to pull the `.removeDuplicates()` inside to each publisher.

```swift
Publishers.CombineLatest3(
    $str1.removeDuplicates(),
    $str2.removeDuplicates(), 
    $image.removeDuplicates()
)
    .sink { (str1, str2, image) in
```

Comment: Another difference is that combineLatest will propagating changes into sink, only once all publishers have had one value assigned to them, where as the approach with "MergeMany" by @jnpdx will fire as soon as one publisher has changes